# scroll not working android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

Scroll does not work in every layout I use like ScrollView or RecyclerView
or any other scrollable Viewgroup

Any help?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/NewsScreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Post your Java files

Comment: Can u try this link, simple example given on recyclerview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095866/getting-android-recyclerview-to-update-view-inside-react-native-component/46313257#46313257

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `recyclerView` inside `scrollView` then your `recyclerView` would not work properly. So, use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Or try this

```
RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: no i didn't use recyclerView inside ScrollView. i used both seperatly inside two different activities

Comment: but the problem that scroll doesn't work . it may work if i slide at very edge of screen and it's not work all time